# Relative Extrema

Tags: functions

I did a question to find relative extrema for the following function: 
$f(x)=x^2$ on $[−2,2].$

The answer said that there is no relative maxima for this function because relative extrema cannot occur at the end points of a domain. 
Why is this so ? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a relative minimum at $0$. But there are also relative *maxima* at $2$ and at $-2$.

The definition for a relative maximum at a point $x_0$ is that $f(x)\leq f(x_0)$ for all $x$ in a sufficiently small neighborhood of $x_0$ (intersected with the function's domain).

For $x_0=2$, for example, it is true that $f(x)\leq f(2)$ for all $x$ in the sufficiently small intervall $(1.5,2.5)\cap[-2,2]=(1.5,2]$ around the point $x_0=2$. So, it is a relative maximum.

There is no reason to believe that relative extrema cannot occur at the boundaries of intervals.

Comment: So can we say that the function  f(x)=x^2 on [−2,2] has its relative maxima at x=+-2 (plus minus two). Please explain in simple language . I am a beginner.

Comment: @AshokSharma I have edited my answer to make it more clear. :)

Comment: Your second answer is incorrect. Neighborhoods here must have a positive radius.

Comment: @Allawonder The common definition is that there is a maximum at $x_0$ if and only if $$\exists_{\delta>0}\forall_{x\in U_\delta(x_0)\cap D}\,f(x_0)\geq f(x)$$ if $D$ is the domain of the function. I don't see a mistake there.

Comment: @st.math We're not talking about a maximum here, but a *relative* maximum. The function in question isn't even defined in a neighborhood of $\pm2.$ I suggest you know exactly what you're saying next time, instead of further confusing the confused. I think you need to check your favourite intro calculus book.

Comment: @Allawonder In two calculus scripts of my university, this is the _exact_ definition of a relative (!) maximum. (Neighborhoods of a point intersected with the function's domain.) The fact that there are different definitions of concepts is not a reason to blame another person's answer as false or confusing.

Comment: @st.math Yes, that's right. But what neighborhood of $\pm2$ are you using here that's in common with the domain. None is possible, because a neighborhood cannot have radius $0.$

Comment: Because the definition does not force it to be a neighborhood, but a non-empty set which results from a neighborhood intersected with the domain (in this case: $(1.5,2]$).

Comment: @st.math The definition states that the function must be defined in a neighborhood of the point in question.

Comment: No, it does not. See my comment to your answer.

Comment: @st.math Any definition that doesn't require that is not justified.

Comment: Why wouldn't it? Again, first read through my comment under your answer; we're talking of the intersection of that interval with the domain, so that the function is well-defined in that interval.

Answer (score -3):

The answer is correct. Why it is so follows immediately from the definition.

There's a difference between an extreme value and a *relative* extreme value of a function at a point. While your function has a maximum value at $\pm2,$ it does not have a *relative* maximum at all. The reason is that relative extreme values by definition can only be defined at a point $c$ first, when the function is defined over an interval of the form $[c-\delta,c+\delta],$ where $\delta>0.$ Another example is $\sqrt x,$ which has no relative minimum at $x=0,$ though it has a minimum there.

In mathematics, the words are very important and never superfluous. Pay attention to such innocuous qualifiers as *relative.*

Good luck in your studies.